# spark-cassandra-connector read throughput unpredictable

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-cassandra-connector

A user reports that the range query throughput is far higher than expected when setting spark.cassandra.input.readsPerSec in the spark-cassandra-connector.

Job dependencies. The Java driver version is set to 4.13.0.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId> com.datastax.oss</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-driver-core-shaded</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

There are two steps in the job (both an FTS):

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.sqlContext().read()
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.option("table", "inbox_user_msg_dummy")
.option("keyspace", "ssmp_inbox2").load();
```

-and-

```
Dataset<Row> olderDataset = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM inbox_user_msg_dummy where app_uuid = 'cb663e07-7bcc-4039-ae97-8fb8e8a9ff77' AND " +
"create_hour < '" + minus180DaysInstant + "'");
```

Job configuration:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
        .setMaster("local[*]") //uncomment while running in local
        .setAppName("inbox-gateway-spark-job")
       .set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
        .set("keyspace", "ssmp_inbox2")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "cass-556799284-1-1276056270.stg.ssmp-inbox2-stg.ms-df-cassandra.stg-az-southcentralus-6.prod.us.walmart.net,
        cass-556799284-2-1276056276.stg.ssmp-inbox2-stg.ms-df-cassandra.stg-az-southcentralus-6.prod.us.walmart.net,
        cass-556799284-3-1276056282.stg.ssmp-inbox2-stg.ms-df-cassandra.stg-az-southcentralus-6.prod.us.walmart.net")
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "ssmp-inbox-app-v2")
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "*")
        .set("spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level", "LOCAL_ONE")
        .set("spark.cassandra.concurrent.reads", "1")
        .set("spark.cassandra.input.readsPerSec", "10")
        .set("spark.cassandra.input.fetch.sizeInRows", "10")
        .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.sizeInMB", "10")
        .set("spark.cores.max", "20")
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "20G")
        .set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "12000")
        .set("spark.cassandra.read.timeoutMS", "200000")
        .set("spark.task.maxFailures", "10")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.localDC", "southcentral");
```

Note that Spark is limiting the actual cores to 16 because workers have 8 cores. There is 1 executor.

When the job runs, it's observed that there are ~22k range queries/s for the first FTS nearly saturating CPU on the cluster, and for the second FTS, there are ~725 range queries/s on the table.

The expectation is that with 16 total Spark cores, the range query throughput would be limited to 160/s (spark.cassandra.input.readsPerSec * spark cores).

Is this reasoning correct? What is the recommendation for controlling read throughput from the spark-cassandra-connector?

I know we've had other users successfully configure this throttle before, but we've never looked closely at what the resulting throughput is. This one does seem to be a big discrepancy though because the two steps are essentially running the same operation - a full table scan. The queries the connector ultimately runs are the same.

The schema:

```
CREATE TABLE ssmp_inbox2.inbox_user_msg_dummy (    
  user_id text,    
  create_hour timestamp,    
  app_uuid text,    
  message_id text,    
  app_name text,    
  create_ts bigint,    
  is_actiontaken boolean,    
  is_compensable boolean,    
  is_deleted boolean,    
  is_read boolean,    
  message_payload text,    
  mini_app_name text,    
  notification text,    
  PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, create_hour, app_uuid), message_id)    
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC)    
  AND additional_write_policy = '99p'    
  AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01    
  AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}    
  AND cdc = false    
  AND comment = ''    
  AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}    
  AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}    
  AND crc_check_chance = 1.0    
  AND default_time_to_live = 0    
  AND extensions = {}    
  AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000    
  AND max_index_interval = 2048    
  AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0    
  AND min_index_interval = 128
  AND read_repair = 'BLOCKING'
  AND speculative_retry = '99p';
```

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM ssmp_inbox2.inbox_user_msg_dummy WHERE token(user_id, create_hour, app_uuid) >= token(G9e7Y4Y, 2023-08-10T04:17:27.234Z, cb663e07-7bcc-4039-ae97-8fb8e8a9ff77) AND token(user_id, create_hour, app_uuid) <= 9121832956220923771 LIMIT 10
```

FWIW, avg partition size is 649 bytes, max is 2.7kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to start is to look here: [Spark Cassandra Connector | Read Tuning Parameters](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#read-tuning-parameters) (Github).

The table is isn't very clear, but `spark.cassandra.concurrent.reads` and `spark.cassandra.input.readsPerSec` are used for joining.

To throttle the full scan you need to use `spark.cassandra.input.throughputMBPerSec`.